# Is there a way to set up pagination for Collections in a Jekyll site?

Tags: github, pagination, jekyll, github-pages

As per Jekyll's doc, pagination for collections is not supported. I've tried to mimic Jekyll posts folder structure for my portfolio collection and then apply a  slightly modified pagination Liquid syntax to work with a portfolio collection with no avail.

Is there a way/workaround in order to set up pagination for Collections in a Jekyll site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jekyll-paginate](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-paginate) only paginate posts.

If you want to paginate collections, you can use [Octopress Paginate](https://github.com/octopress/paginate/) but it's not supported by github ([for now](https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/announcement-retiring-jekyll-paginate/1004)).

Comment: Sure. Thanks for making it clear. I've came across Octopress Paginate, but as long as I'm building a jekyll site fully supported by github pages (without any plugins dependencies), I was hoping for a pure Liquid syntax workaround, perhaps with the help of some js function or jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to assign prev and next tags to "fake" pagination for your collections. Here is how anjesh did it:

```
{% for c in site.tripcollection %}
{% if c.title == page.title %}
  {% assign thisPost = c %}
  {% if forloop.index == 1 %}
    {% assign prevflag = 0 %}
    {% assign nextflag = 1 %}
  {% elsif forloop.index == forloop.length %}
    {% assign prevflag = 1 %}
    {% assign nextflag = 0 %}
  {% else %}
    {% assign prevflag = 1 %}
    {% assign nextflag = 1 %}
  {% endif %}  
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% for c in site.tripcollection %}
  {% if c.title == page.title %}
    {% assign prevflag = 0 %}
  {% endif %}
  {% if prevflag == 1 %}
    {% assign prevPost = c %}
    {% assign page.previous = c %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% if nextflag == 1 %}
  {% for c in site.tripcollection %}
    {% if foundPost == 1 %}
      {% assign getNext = 1 %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if c.title == page.title %}
      {% assign foundPost = 1 %}        
    {% endif %}
    {% if getNext == 1%}
      {% assign nextPost = c %}
      {% assign page.next = c %}
      {% assign foundPost = 0 %}
      {% assign getNext = 0 %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

<div id="post-nav">
    <div >    
        {% if prevPost.url %}
        <a class="prev" href="{{prevPost.url}}">
            <span>&lt; {{prevPost.title}}</span>
        </a> 
        {% endif %} 
        {% if nextPost.url %} 
        <a class="next" href="{{nextPost.url}}">
            <span>{{nextPost.title}} &gt;</span>
        </a> 
        {% endif %} 
    </div>
</div>
```

You can read his whole post here: [Get Pagination working in Jekyll Collection in Github pages](http://anjesh.github.io/2015/01/25/collection-pagination-working-github-pages/)

Comment: This doesn't look like it is related to pagination: instead it looks like it is adding next/previous links to individual posts in the collection.